# How connect words in a text file

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, cut

I have a file in following format:

```
B: that


I: White


I: House


B: the
I: emergency


I: rooms


B: trauma
I: centers
```

What I need to do is to read line by line from the top, if the line begin with B then remove B:
If it begin with I: then remove I: and connect to the previous one (the previous one is processed in the same rule).

Expected Output:

```
that White House
the emergency rooms
trauma centers
```

What I tried:

```
while read line
do
    string=$line

    echo $string | grep "B:"  1>/dev/null 
    if [ `echo $?` -eq 0 ] //if start with " B: "
    then
        $newstring= echo ${var:4} //cut first 4 characters which including B: and space

        echo $string | grep "I:"  1>/dev/null 
    if [ `echo $?` -eq 0 ] //if start with " I: "
    then
        $newstring= echo ${var:4} //cut first 4 characters which including I: and space
done < file.txt
```

What I don't know is how to put it back to the line (in the file) and how to connect the line to the previous processed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk print the second field of `I:` and `B:` records. The variable `first` is used to control the newline output.

`/B:/` searches for the `B:` pattern. This pattern marks the start of the record. If the record is NOT the first, then a newline is printed, then the data $2 is printed.

If the pattern found is `I:` the data $2 (the second field which follows `I:` is printed.

```
awk 'BEGIN{first=1}
     /B:/ { if (first) first=0; else  print "";  printf("%s ", $2); }
     /I:/ { printf("%s ", $2) }
     END {print ""}' filename
```

Comment: Yes, it works! It is also very nice and short answer, would b perfect if there is comment about the parameters!

Comment: Added some more narrative - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" '{a[NR]=$0}
           /^ B:/{print line;line=$2}
           /^ I:/{line=line" "$2}
           END{
               if(a[NR]!~/^B/)
               {print line}
          }' Your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/\n$//;s/\n\s*I://;ta;s/B://g;s/^\s*//;P;D' file
```

or:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!N' -e 's/\n$//' -e 's/\n\s*I://' -e 'ta' -e 's/B://g' -e 's/^\s*//' -e 'P' -e 'D' file
```

Comment: I use Mac and it said : sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: @user1314404 it does not need the `-r` option however as you are using a Mac you will probably need to separate each instruction  and use tthe `-e` flag. See edit

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^B/ {printf "\n%s",$2} /^I/ {printf " %s",$2}' file

that White House
the emergency rooms
trauma centers
```

Shorten it some

```
awk '/./ {printf /^B/?"\n%s":" %s",$2}' file
```

Comment: Thank you, if it is allowed to accept two answers I will choose you. But I have to kudo the fastest answer.

Comment: No problem, you can still click the up arrow (This answer is usefull) :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting solution using awk auto-split on RS patterns. Note that this is a bit sensitive to variations in the input format:

```
<infile awk 1 RS='(^|\n)B: ' | awk 1 RS='\n+I: ' ORS=' ' | grep -v '^ *$'
```

Output:

```
that White House
the emergency rooms
trauma centers
```

This works at least with GNU awk and Mikes awk.